# Reload jquery script after resize display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I have a problem with jquery script if page size was changed. For example - if you open site on the phone, then open and close menu, then rotate phone from vertical to horizontal and open menu again - the block will not shown.

I use this script

```
return $(document).ready(function() {
  (function($) {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
      $('#header-menu').css('display', 'none');
      $('header.grid-container').css('display', 'none');
      return $('#toggle-mobile-menu').click(function() {
        $('#header-menu').toggle();
        return $('header.grid-container').toggle();
      });
    }
  })(jQuery);
});
```

I need some hook maybe, to reload script if screen was changed, without reload page. I tried to use `$(window).resize()` but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible Jquery gets put into the DOM and would require a page refresh in order for the script to change.

You should consider using AJAX instead.

Comment: You would have to refresh the page.

Comment: thanks, okay will try to solve with AJAX, or will find another way. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You should have no problem solving it with AJAX, Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your script is triggered only once after loading all DOM elements (Your are checking the screen width and if condition is done you are triggering the event). I suggest move styling to CSS (media queries) and use jquery only for binding events

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    #header-menu,
    .grid-container { display: none; }

    #toggle-mobile-menu { display: block; } // or whatever
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('#toggle-mobile-menu').on('click', function() {
        $('#header-menu').toggle();
        $('header.grid-container').toggle();
    }
});
```